# How to access httpOnly cookies in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js, apollo-client

Can anyone suggest what would be the best way to access tokens from httpOnly cookies?

I'm using Next.js 12.x.x as the front end (`http://localhost:3000`).

My API server runs separately (`http://localhost:4000`).

Once login, the API server returns the JWT token. I am storing tokens in cookies - httpOnly. I am using Apollo client and hooks like `useQuery`.

What I know is:

1. httpOnly can't be read from the client side with JavaScript.
2. If I make a request to Next.js API, from the request, I can read the cookies and get the token.

```js
export default async function (req, res) { 
  const { cookies } = req;
  const jwt = cookies.token;
}
```

3. I can access the token from `getServerSideProps`

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const jwt = context.req.cookies.token;
        
}
```

BUT,

1. I'm using an Apollo client.
2. I want to use `useQuery` hooks.
3. My API needs token info to return responses, which are running separately.
4. I can NOT use hooks in `getServerSideProps`.

I need to pass `Authorization` in the header.
Can anyone help me to understand the best and most secure way to get the token and add in the header of apolloClient?
I want to avoid creating APIs at frontend (Next.js).

`_app.js` look like below.

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { ApolloProvider, ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';

export  function MyApp({Component, pageProps} ) {

  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  });
  
  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    const token = "HOW TO FIND YOU ?????";
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }
  });
  
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
export default MyApp;
```

Comment: You can use `getInitialProps` inside your `_app.js`, as then pass the token to the client. However in this way you are going to have the wole app SSR. i think use next.js custom api ins the better way

Comment: Have you considered not using an httpOnly cookie?

Comment: @juliomalves - No, still using httpOnly cookies and using getServerSideProps for every route to validate valid authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is using proxy with api routes and pass the auth token to header on every request.

Read this [article](https://maxschmitt.me/posts/next-js-http-only-cookie-auth-tokens) to understand more

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33758223)